# Printf Statement

Tags: java, printf

Is there a way to have the radius shown in this printf statement located at the bottom? So far, I only have the area shown.

```
public class Circle
{
private double radius;
private double Area;

public void setRadius(double rad)
{
    radius = rad;
}

public void calculateArea( )
{
    Area=Math.PI*(radius*radius);
}

public void printArea( )
{
    System.out.printf("A Circle of radius has area %.4f", Area);
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: This question shows no sign of research before being asked here.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to show the radius in the print statement. You are already having it in the field 'radius' right..so can you not do something like

```
 System.out.println("A Circle of radius " + radius + " has area " + Area);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
System.out.printf("A Circle of radius %4f has area %.4f", radius, Area);
```

Also to effectively use `printf` and `format` methods, just check out the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)